# Improving a constructor

Tags: php, oop

Alright, I'm working on making a Member class for my website.  I want to make it as optimized as possible.  Currently, the constructor can take ($resource) either an int (to grab info from one member in the database, based on id) or an array of ints (to grab multiple members from the database, and store them in an array member variable).

I would like to know if there are any inprovements I can make with my block of code below, before I move on to creating more parts of my website.  What could be changed to make it better?  Is there a better layout I should follow for doing this kind of thing?

```
public function __construct($resource) {
  global $database;
     if (is_string($resource) || is_int($resource)) {
            $resource = (int)$resource;
   $query = $database->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id = {$resource} LIMIT 1");
   $row = $database->get_row($query);

         foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
               $this->field[$key] = $value;
            }
  } else if (is_array($resource)) {
   $query = $database->query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE member_id IN(" . implode(",",$resource) . ")");
   while ($member = $database->get_row($query)) {
    $this->member_list[$member['member_id']] = $member;
   }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You could start with correct indentation for one, this is hard to follow...

Comment: I can't stand poorly formatted code. Get yourself some [proper brace style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Allman_style_.28bsd_in_Emacs.29).

Comment: @format comments, SO editor doesn't help.

Comment: Yeah my intents were working in my editor, dunno why they didn't here. D:

Answer (score 5):

Some thoughts:

- Globals are bad
- Database calls should be isolated to a data access layer, ideally of the ORM variety so that you aren't writing manual SQL.
- What if `$resource` is `"ddd"`, do you want the member with a `member_id` of `1` ?
- You aren't protecting against SQL injection.
- Shouldn't your `member_list` be creating new `Member` objects (or whatever this class is called) rather than simply appending the row data?

Comment: I wanted to lower the amount of queries I would be running, so thats why member_list is an array of the rows from the MySQL query

Comment: @Chiggins this is exactly why your constructor should just take row data and not do a query itself.

Comment: So, instead of performing the MySQL query inside the constructor, do the MySQL elsewhere, then pass the row to the constructor?

Comment: Yes. I'd have two constructors, one takes no parameters and calls your database layer access code. The second takes row data and uses that.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, don't do work in a constructor.  Secondly, there are many packages out there that do exactly what you're trying to do, and do it VERY well.

What you're trying to write is called a Model.  It's a class that mirrors a table in the database. Use a mature ORM (Object Relational Mapper) package such as [Propel](http://www.propelorm.org/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) for automatically generating classes based off of database schemas. I personally recommend Propel over Doctrine (though they are both great packages).

Also, I'd recommend that you use the [symfony php framework](http://symfony.com/), which integrates Propel as its ORM (again, you can use Doctrine as an alternative ORM with Symfony).

Lastly, don't use globals.  Write a class around any resource that access. Making a static call to retrieve its singleton instance such as Database::getInstance() is a much preferred way of accessing the database (or any other) resource.

Best of luck

Comment: +1 for dont do work in a constructor. http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-constructor-does-real-work/